# How do you defeat Brekker?

Tags: dragon-age-2

How do you manage this fight? I'm at level 16 and it's completely impossible. The rogues just take out my party like nothing. Doesn't matter what I do. I have read various guides but nothin seems to help. I've even tried to retreat back a bit but that usually leaves one character dead since they can one shot my mages. CC doesn't seem to help because they vanish before it lands. AoE doesn't seem to help either, they still backstab you. Also, the rogues can take a massive ammount of punishment so it's very hard for me to burn them down quick enough.

As for gear, I've been going through every shop I can find and I have the best gear that I know of and it still isn't enough.

How do you handle this fight? And I'm only playing on normal.

Comment: The problem with this is that I never had a problem with him so I can't really tell what you're doing wrong